# write data in to a csv according to headers names, which indicate occurrences of items

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, header

I need to enter data in to csv using headers and put a value if the flag is available in the event else zero it. Required output is:

[image: required image]  I am currently getting:

[image: getting image]

This is my current code, I would like to know how to generate my desired output:

inputs for code is counter1-4 shown below :

```
OrderedDict([('flags=40', 3971), ('flags=10004', 6244), ('flags=10100', 236), ('flags=90002', 2), ('flags=80', 2009), ('flags=10080', 5421), ('flags=4', 2886), ('flags=100', 227), ('flags=80002', 58), ('flags=10040', 8990), ('flags=0', 5)])

OrderedDict([('flags=40', 16), ('flags=10004', 6244), ('flags=10100', 236), ('flags=90002', 2), ('flags=10080', 5421), ('flags=4', 16), ('flags=80002', 11), ('flags=10040', 8990), ('flags=0', 4), ('Total', 20940)])
OrderedDict([('flags=4', 1332), ('flags=40', 1839), ('flags=80002', 3), ('flags=100', 197), ('flags=80', 935), ('Total', 4306)])
OrderedDict([('Total', 0)])
OrderedDict([('flags=40', 2116), ('flags=80', 1074), ('flags=4', 1538), ('flags=100', 30), ('flags=80002', 44), ('flags=0', 1), ('Total', 4803)])

dat = 1        
with open(outputcsv,'wb') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv,delimiter=',')
    appname = inputfile[:-3]
    writer.writerow(appname.split(','))
    for x in threads:
        writer.writerows([x.split(',')])
        #w.writeheader([x.split(',')])
        if dat == 1:
            w = csv.DictWriter(outcsv,counter1.keys())
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerow(counter1)
        elif dat == 2:
            w = csv.DictWriter(outcsv,counter2.keys())
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerow(counter2)
        elif dat == 3:
            w = csv.DictWriter(outcsv,counter3.keys())
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerow(counter3)
        elif dat == 4:
            w = csv.DictWriter(outcsv,counter4.keys())
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerow(counter4)
        dat = dat +1    
        writer.writerows('\n')
```

code for how threads are being read:

```
 exampleFile = open('top_tasks.csv')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
exampleData = list(exampleReader)
thread1 = exampleData[11][0]
thread2 = exampleData[12][0]
thread3 = exampleData[13][0]
thread4 = exampleData[14][0]
threads = [thread1,thread2,thread3,thread4]
```

Comment: You should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  In particular, you have not provided the input data.

Comment: text which i'm parsing is a huge file from which i'm extracting events with flags

Comment: Yes, but the point of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is that you can get a small example that is representive of the problem, and allows us, and you, to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code meets your requirements:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv

# build an OrderedDict of all keys
all_keys = OrderedDict()

# first column gets name of data set
all_keys[data_set_name] = data_set_name

# collect all of the known keys, and insert the thread name
for counter, thread in zip(counters, threads):
    all_keys.update(counter)
    counter[data_set_name] = thread

with open(outputcsv, 'wb') as outcsv:
    # using all known keys, create a csv writer
    w = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames=all_keys.keys())

    # output the header and data rows
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(counters)
```

Data Used:

```
outputcsv = 'output.csv'
counters = [
    OrderedDict(
        [('flags=40', 3971), ('flags=10004', 6244), ('flags=10100', 236),
         ('flags=90002', 2), ('flags=80', 2009), ('flags=10080', 5421),
         ('flags=4', 2886), ('flags=100', 227), ('flags=80002', 58),
         ('flags=10040', 8990), ('flags=0', 5)]),

    OrderedDict(
        [('flags=40', 16), ('flags=10004', 6244), ('flags=10100', 236),
         ('flags=90002', 2), ('flags=10080', 5421), ('flags=4', 16),
         ('flags=80002', 11), ('flags=10040', 8990), ('flags=0', 4),
         ('Total', 20940)]),
    OrderedDict([('flags=4', 1332), ('flags=40', 1839), ('flags=80002', 3),
                 ('flags=100', 197), ('flags=80', 935), ('Total', 4306)]),
    OrderedDict([('Total', 0)]),
    OrderedDict([('flags=40', 2116), ('flags=80', 1074), ('flags=4', 1538),
                 ('flags=100', 30), ('flags=80002', 44), ('flags=0', 1),
                 ('Total', 4803)]),
]

# code assumes thread names are in a list, make some sample names
threads = ['thread%d' % (i+1) for i in range(len(counters))]

# first column header if the name of the data set
data_set_name = 'CandyCrush 1'
```

Comment: yeah this did works as expected, but the questions remains ,I need to put thread names in each row as an indicator for which threads has which flag events, can you help with that

Comment: Yes that is easy to add, but only if the [data is known](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and associated with the other source data.

Comment: Thread name changes with the app,  thread name is not consistent

Comment: Yes, I believe the thread name changes.  But it will need to be known by the program, and associated with the data.  The sample data you gave does not include the thread name.  If you can show how the thread names is a associated with the sample data, I can easily edit my example to include it.

Comment: threads are being read from a file called top_tasks.csv and assigned to threads combing all 4 top threads, see code for this in edit above